# Which is a better approach to persist the spring state machine context or restore the state machine using the state enum on entity object?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, state-machine, spring-statemachine

I am new to spring state machine and trying to understand which is a better approach whether to persist the state context in a database or to restore the state machine from the domain object?

I am trying to implement state machine to handle an e-commerce Order fulfillment process. I have come across 2 different approaches to restore the state machine

1. Persist the state machine context as described [here](https://github.com/otrosien/spring-statemachine-jpa-and-rest)
2. Restore from the domain object as described [here](https://github.com/spring-tips/statemachine/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/orderservice/OrderServiceApplication.java)

I am not able to understand the pros and cons of each method and how to determine which is a better approach for processing large number of orders per day.